# How to resize a raster to the same extents of an equivalent raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, alignment

So here's the problem

I have a georeferenced orthomosaic which I used to generate land cover data.
During the pixel classification phase of land cover study, I had to use other softwares to help me to classify everything the way I wanted and when I finally imported it back to QGIS, I got this:

[image]

Looks like the top left corner is the same, but somehow I underscaled it and now I need it back to the old extents. Both files are georeferenced in the same projection. Any ideas on how can I do that?

GDALINFO: https://pastebin.com/hM6GvaL8

Smaller raster (needs to be fixed):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: uso_solo2.tif
Size is 12777, 8410
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 22S",
    GEOGCS["SIRGAS 2000",
        DATUM["Sistema_de_Referencia_Geocentrico_para_las_AmericaS_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6674"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4674"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-51],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31982"]]
Origin = (542062.706200000015087,7524576.377299999818206)
Pixel Size = (0.053355701651406,-0.053355707491080)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  542062.706, 7524576.377) ( 50d35'29.01"W, 22d23' 3.54"S)
Lower Left  (  542062.706, 7524127.656) ( 50d35'28.96"W, 22d23'18.14"S)
Upper Right (  542744.432, 7524576.377) ( 50d35' 5.16"W, 22d23' 3.48"S)
Lower Right (  542744.432, 7524127.656) ( 50d35' 5.12"W, 22d23'18.08"S)
Center      (  542403.569, 7524352.017) ( 50d35'17.06"W, 22d23'10.81"S)
Band 1 Block=12777x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=12777x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=12777x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=12777x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Bigger raster (its the right one):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: D:\PROJETOS\MARUBAYASHI_LAUDO\PRODUTOS\ORTOMOSAICO\ORTO_MARUBAYASHI.tif
       D:\PROJETOS\MARUBAYASHI_LAUDO\PRODUTOS\ORTOMOSAICO\ORTO_MARUBAYASHI.tif.ovr
Size is 59993, 39491
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 22S",
    GEOGCS["SIRGAS 2000",
        DATUM["Sistema_de_Referencia_Geocentrico_para_las_AmericaS_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6674"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4674"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-51],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31982"]]
Origin = (542059.236558826058172,7524588.587958189658821)
Pixel Size = (0.053244800000000,-0.053244799999993)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  542059.237, 7524588.588) ( 50d35'29.13"W, 22d23' 3.15"S)
Lower Left  (  542059.237, 7522485.898) ( 50d35'28.93"W, 22d24'11.53"S)
Upper Right (  545253.552, 7524588.588) ( 50d33'37.42"W, 22d23' 2.85"S)
Lower Right (  545253.552, 7522485.898) ( 50d33'37.21"W, 22d24'11.24"S)
Center      (  543656.394, 7523537.243) ( 50d34'33.17"W, 22d23'37.19"S)
Band 1 Block=59993x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 3194x2103, 1597x1052, 799x526, 400x263, 200x132
  Unit Type: metre
Band 2 Block=59993x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 3194x2103, 1597x1052, 799x526, 400x263, 200x132
  Unit Type: metre
Band 3 Block=59993x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 3194x2103, 1597x1052, 799x526, 400x263, 200x132
  Unit Type: metre
```

Comment: What's the file type? Does it have another file with it that ends in "w"? (i.e. a `.tiff` with a `.tfw`)?

Comment: @CSouza, there is not enough information in the question to provide an answer. Please, [Edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/312681/edit) to include the output of the [gdalinfo](https://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) command (at the console) or the [Raster Information](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#raster-information) tool (in QGIS) for both files or layers.

Comment: Yeah initially it was a geotiff, but then I edited it on Photoshop, so I generated a tfw (I guess I made a mistake here) and then I imported it back to QGIS. Then I made a few more adjustements (filters etc) and finally exported it to geotiff one more time.

Comment: Did it work? The .tfw is a file which determines the position, orientation and scale of its respective .tiff file. You should just have to make sure that the new .tiff has the same parameters as the old one. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: If these two images were originally had the same extent and grid size, you can use `listgeo` then `geotifcp` to copy the settings of Bigger Raster to Smaller Raster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed it by creating a new world file based on the bigger raster and then overwriting it on the smaller geotiff with the following command:    `geotifcp -e bigraster.tfw  smallraster.tif newraster.tif`